# Qual a mínima lagura de um dispositivo móvel?

Tags: css, mobile

Meu site é organizado para se adaptar a tamanhos de telas diferentes através do CSS @media's, porém a lagura minima é 320px (width). Imagino que existam dispositivos com larguras menores, mas em uma quantidade desconsiderável... isso procede? ou me recomendam estilizar uma largura menor?

Comment: Vc tem que se preocupar mais com o seu público alvo e a persona que vc usou para construir a sua arquitetura. De qq forma, por aqui vc pode ver que resoluções abaixo de 320 nem aparecem nos gráficos... http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/mobile/worldwide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menor resolução para **smartphone** é `QVGA (240x320)`

abaixo disso só o **smartwatch**

**apple watch**

```
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}
```

**Moto 360 watch**

```
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

> Imagino que existam dispositivos com larguras menores, mas em uma
>   quantidade desconsiderável... isso procede?

Sim